# Failed to initialize plugin: magentowidget on magento 2.4.4 Editor

Tags: admin, wysiwyg, magento2.4.4, editor

I am having below error on the magento 2.4.4p2 commerce version when upgrading from 2.3.5 commerce

`Failed to initialize plugin: magentowidget`

This happened on the admin WYSIWYG editor

I have done

`composer install`

`sudo rm -rf generated/* var/view_preprocessed/* pub/static/*`

`bin/magento setup:upgrade`

`bin/magento setup:di:compile`

`bin/magento cache:clean`

`sudo chown -R farhan:www-data .`

`sudo chmod -R 777 .`

but still does not fix this issue

anyone know if its related to databases or configuration

the one at another environment, staging server seems to be working fine, but the db there is 30gb to be downloaded and imported into my local machine

[image]

Update : I found this error on the log using `tail -f var/log/*`

````
[2022-12-01T01:54:27.057346+00:00] report.ERROR: The contents from the "static/adminhtml/Magento/backend/en_US/Magento_Cms/images/wysiwyg_skin_image.png" file can't be read. Warning!file_get_contents(static/adminhtml/Magento/backend/en_US/Magento_Cms/images/wysiwyg_skin_image.png): failed to open stream: No such file or directory [] []

==> var/log/system.log <==
[2022-12-01T01:54:27.057346+00:00] report.ERROR: The contents from the "static/adminhtml/Magento/backend/en_US/Magento_Cms/images/wysiwyg_skin_image.png" file can't be read. Warning!file_get_contents(static/adminhtml/Magento/backend/en_US/Magento_Cms/images/wysiwyg_skin_image.png): failed to open stream: No such file or directory [] []

==> var/log/debug.log <==
[2022-12-01T01:54:27.057346+00:00] report.ERROR: The contents from the "static/adminhtml/Magento/backend/en_US/Magento_Cms/images/wysiwyg_skin_image.png" file can't be read. Warning!file_get_contents(static/adminhtml/Magento/backend/en_US/Magento_Cms/images/wysiwyg_skin_image.png): failed to open stream: No such file or directory [] []```
````

Answer (score 0):

I ran in the same problem today. This is caused by TinyMCE going from version 4 to 5. You probably have some code that overwrites one of their files and was not updated to their modifications.

Mine was this one :

```
vendor/magento/magento2-base/lib/web/mage/adminhtml/wysiwyg/tiny_mce/plugins/magentovariable/editor_plugin.js
```

Comment: Thank you, finally fixed the issue

Comment: I copy

vendor/magento/magento2-base/lib/web/mage/adminhtml/wysiwyg/tiny_mce/plugins/magentovariable/editor_plugin.js
to
lib/web/mage/adminhtml/wysiwyg/tiny_mce/plugins/magentovariable/editor_plugin.js

and
vendor/magento/magento2-base/lib/web/mage/adminhtml/wysiwyg/tiny_mce/plugins/magentowidget/editor_plugin.js
to
lib/web/mage/adminhtml/wysiwyg/tiny_mce/plugins/magentowidget/editor_plugin.js